# How to recompile 32-bit MS Access file for 64-bit office

Tags: ms-access, migration, ms-office, ms-access-2016

I'm working on a Windows 10 migration project and one issue I've run into is some of the end-users have 32-bit .accde files that cannot be opened in 64-bit Access. Target version is click-to-run Office 365, current version is Office 2010 running on Windows 7.

According to [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261), these files can be recompiled

> ... you can recompile 32-bit .mde, .ade, and .accde files to make them 64-bit compatible.

Trick is, I'm not an MS Access guy and even so far on this project my experience with the tech is super thin. I can't figure out how to perform this recompilation. I've done quite a bit of searching on the web and haven't found anything so I'm turning to the collective braintrust here.

Let me know what other details I can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Review https://www.devhut.net/2017/04/13/access-x32-vs-x64-compatibility/.

> As a general rule, a database (in accdb file format) developed on
>   Access x32 should run fine on Access x64 and vice versa.
>   ...
>   Compiled versions (accde file format) must be compiled on the same
>   version of the application they will be run on. So an:
>   x32 accde must be compiled and run on Access/Office x32
>   x64 accde must be compiled and run on Access/Office x64

Recompiling requires using original adp/mdb/accdb file to create a new executable. With original db: File > Save & Publish > Make ACCDE

Might require some code changes first. Continuing with linked article:

> You will need to review all of you API calls providing conditional compilation directives containing modified API declaration that are compatible with both x32 and x64.